# Refresh a <apex:pageBlockTable> in a visualforce page

Tags: salesforce, visualforce

I need to refresh a apex:pageBlockTable in a VF page.I tried it.But did n't achieve.Please help me to find a solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can't <strike>refresh</strike> rerender `<apex:pageBlockTable>` and `<apex:dataTable>`.

Instead you can refresh their parent container. Anything will do - pageBlock, pageBlockSection... if you don't have anything just wrap them in outputPanel and it'll be good enough as long as it has id set.

Comment: can you please elaborate your answer? I am having same issue..I am having one grid and I want to refresh my grid when any change occur in it's controller manually.I dont want to refresh whole page .I just want to refresh the grid.. @eyescream